# "unauthorized_client" error when using PHP client to refreshToken with Google API client?

Tags: php, ios, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am requesting access to the user's data from an IOS app using this code from the GoogleSignIn pod

```
 [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setScopes:@[ ... ];
 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```

I then receive the accessToken and the refreshToken in the appDelegate and I send that to the server running PHP and using this google client library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) ... for the first hour everything is working fine and the access token is valid and allowing me access to all the scopes. Then after an hour the access token expires and I try to refresh it using this code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(<app name>);
$client->setDeveloperKey(<google_oauth_developer_key>);
$client->setClientSecret(<google_oauth_client_secret>);
$client->setClientId(<google_oauth_client_id>);
$client->refreshToken("1/12ju3ZZim-r6co195lIVNNvzBq9x5G64GJCWkYsOQ18");
```

and the "refreshToken" function above returns this error

```
=> [
     "error" => "unauthorized_client",
     "error_description" => "Unauthorized",
   ]
```

It's worth noting that the `app name`, `google_oauth_developer_key`, `google_oauth_client_secret`, and `google_oauth_client_id` have not changed. They are the same ones that were working earlier to retrieve the user's contacts, calendar events, etc when the access token was not yet expired.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out what I did wrong. I originally followed these instructions https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in which assume you need online access only, but I actually need offline access to the scopes so I followed these instructions https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access and it works now. So instead of having the IOS app send up the access token and the refresh token separately like this

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {

    if (!error) {
        NSString *accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken;
        NSString *refreshToken = user.authentication.refreshToken;
```

I simply have it send up the `serverAuthCode` like this

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {

      if (!error) {
        NSString *serverAuthCode = user.serverAuthCode;
```

and then on the server I run this code to get the access token

```
$access_token = $client->authenticate($google_server_auth_code);
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

and then when the access token expires I run this to refresh it

```
$access_token = $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually use your refresh token at some point.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        $client->getAccessToken();
```

Code ripped from my [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php) sample

**Note**

Also remember that refresh tokens are user / client based.  So if the token was generated by one client then a different client will probably not be able to use it.   I will be very surprised if you can use a refresh token created in Ios code in a php application.  The client types are different.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think separate clients DO work because it lets me access all the scopes and everything works fine up until the access token expires... the App is still the same, just different client IDs

Comment: Well using the access token without a client id and refreshing the access token using a different client id are two different things.  Give the code a try see what happens.

Comment: I gave the code a shot and it failed with the error ```PHP Notice:  Undefined index: expires_in in /app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 484``` ... when I called ```$client->isAccessTokenExpired()```... Could you show me what an access token looks like ? Mine looks like this ->  `ya29.GluSBn-ektRuma45i1ILoKXGYWkSDv5XgAY84px2OZ0-5X2Efjsja2Ij4ne-Zun75w5rw3NVok9-Sj9G3sdW1n4jD7mH9_4h4CT_Rm5xqtNuDjeWB0jSqUZss-Pf`, but I think it needs to be a json object in order to invoke these other functions successfully ( like the ```isAccessTokenExpired``` function  for example )

Comment: Probably because it cant validate an access token from IOS based upon a different client id.  but it can use it.   I suggest you pick a technology.    However out of curiosity you did create both clients under the same project in Google developer console right?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out